# Powershell - Can't completely delete specific registry key on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, registry

I am creating a script that resets file associations for a specific extension. Here's my code so-far:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$File,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [String]
    $BackupFolder="C:\Tools\00 Powershell Registry Backups"
)

if(!(Test-IsAdmin)){
    Request-AdminRights
    Exit
}

if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $BackupFolder -PathType Container)){
    New-Item $BackupFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
}

$TargetExtension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($File)

$Result = Invoke-VBMessageBox "Are you absolutely sure you want to reset the file extension $($TargetExtension.ToUpper())?" -Title "Are you sure?" -Icon Question -BoxType OKCancel -DefaultButton 2

if($Result -eq "Cancel"){
    Exit
}

$CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-fff"
$FExtension = ($TargetExtension.ToUpper()).TrimStart('.')

regedit /e /y "$BackupFolder\$FExtension $CurrentDate HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$TargetExtension

regedit /e /y "$BackupFolder\$FExtension $CurrentDate CurrentVersion-Explorer-FileExts.reg" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\$TargetExtension

cmd.exe /c assoc $TargetExtension=

Remove-Item Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$TargetExtension -Force -Verbose -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\$TargetExtension -Force -Verbose -Recurse


Read-Host "Press any key to continue:"
```

1. The keys are correctly backed up to my backup folder.
2. `Remove-Item Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$TargetExtension -Force -Verbose -Recurse` works properly and deletes the `.txt` key from HKCR completely.
3. `Remove-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\$TargetExtension -Force -Verbose -Recurse` does not work and throws an error saying the key doesn't exist.

[image: Error]

Can someone lead me to an answer? I'm not sure why this isn't working. The key definitely exists:

[image: Key Exists]

### Edit 1

I think the issue is permissions related. If I inspect the permissions for subkey "UserChoice" within the ".txt" key, there is a `DENY` permissions entry:

[image: DENY subkey]

I found a post [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0aa7d56e-4d7b-4c63-9bad-352b8554b5b2/a-problem-using-powershell-to-delete-a-registry-key-with-special-permissions?forum=winserverpowershell) where the user has a similar problem. But I tried implementing the answer there and it still doesn't work.

How can I remove this DENY permission entry within Pwsh? I think if I can figure that out, it should delete correctly with no complaints.

Comment: Jay, you're code is checking that you are running as Admin and the ACL shows Admin has full control so this shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Jay,

You may need the -recurse argument on your remove-item command since there is a sub-key.

Here's code I use and have never had a problem with.

```
Function Remove-RegistryItem {

[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [String] $RegPath,
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
       [String] $KeyName = ""
)

   If ((Test-Path $RegPath)) {

     If ($KeyName -ne '') { #Delete the key Value
       $RIArgs = @{Path         = $RegPath
                   Name         = $KeyName
                   Force        = $True}
       Remove-ItemProperty @RIArgs | Out-Null
     }
     Else {     #Remove the Registry Path & Children!
       $RIArgs = @{Path         = $RegPath
                   Force        = $True
                   Recurse      = $True}
       Remove-Item @RIArgs
     }

   } #End If ((Test-Path...

} #End Function Remove-RegistryItem
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot. However I really think it's a permissions issue. See the edit to my post for more information. But I'll try out your function anyway!

Comment: Just tested your code and I'm getting the same error: 

Cannot find path 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\' because it does not exist.

Comment: Jay, why is the C:\Users\xxx\Desktop in there? That's not part of a registry key.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that, I have no idea why I put that there. Anyway, I ran your code as follows: 

`Remove-RegistryItem -RegPath "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts" -KeyName ".txt"`

There is no error, but it doesn't remove the key.

I also tried:

`Remove-RegistryItem -RegPath "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt"`

And still it didn't remove the key. Can you try on your end?

Comment: Jay, still working on this. Thought I had it but try to confirm and not so! I've tried manually deleting it via RegEdit and that worked so I know it can be done. I'll keep working on this and get back if I can make it work.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thank you so very much for spending your time trying to fix my problem. I appreciate it more than you know.

Comment: The `-RegPath` should either start with `Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\...` or `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\...`